# What is a good mechanism for storing `jq` filters on disk?

Tags: jq

The typical usage of [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]
```

means that, for example, to pretty-print a file one would write

```
jq -s '.' input.json output.json
```

yet as the `<filter>` grows, it's cleaner to store it on disk, as a full-fledged program.

We might want to do that because:

1. We're using the filter in multiple contexts/files, and do not want the risks of cutting-and-pasting.
2. Storing the filter in a Makefile, means that we have to introduce trailing backslashes, which diminish the readability of the code.
3. If we're lucky, we may have a mode in some editor that makes it easier to catch subtle mistakes in the code.

The best one can do with `awk` (which is to CSV files what jq is to JSON files) is to save a file with a `.awk` extension, make it executable and write on the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
```

or

```
#!/opt/local/bin/gawk -f
```

What is a good mechanism for storing `jq` filters on disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do exactly the same. From `man jq`:

> ```
>    ·   -f filename / --from-file filename:
>
>        Read  filter  from  the  file rather than from a command line, like
>        awk´s -f option. You can also use ´#´ to make comments.
> ```

So for example:

```
$ cat myfilter.jq
#!/usr/bin/jq --from-file

.[].foo // empty
```

and make sure it's executable

```
$ chmod +x myfilter.jq
```

then

```
$ printf '[{"foo": "bar"},{"goo": "bar"},{"foo": "bam"}]' | ./myfilter.jq
"bar"
"bam"
```